# Laravel ID primary auto increment alternative

Tags: php, laravel, auto-increment

In my application most of the IDs (user_id, classroom_id, post_id, assessment_id and so on) are publicly available which means that they are either in the URL or the name of a directory. For safety reasons I‘d like to have 10 character random IDs for every table instead of the auto incremented ones.

I could use a timestamp but this isn‘t really unique and with random numbers added it would get much longer (for example I would have to add 4 random numbers to handle up to 10.000 DB inserts to a table per second... purely hypothetically it's not scaleable).

Now I’d prefer to create a **10 character random ID**, this would give me **10 billion possible ID combinations**. So the chance to generate a duplicate is very small and the length is also acceptable.

```php
use Keygen;

$id = Keygen::numeric(10)->generate();
```

Do you think that my thoughts make sense? And does anyone know if using 10 character primary IDs would affect my DB performance negatively? Thanks!

Comment: May be worth trying something like https://github.com/spatie/laravel-binary-uuid

Comment: YouTube uses 11 of what appears to be alphanumeric characters. If your concern is how things look like on a URL then 6 alphanumeric characters probably look better than 10 numbers and give you about 57 billion possible values. If your concern is storage then 6 alphanumeric ASCII characters take 6 bytes but a long takes 8 so is slightly smaller. On the other hand if you do use a long then you're going to really waste it because longs can hold up to about 20 digits

Comment: @KyleWardle Unfortunately UUID isn't URL friendly.

Comment: @apokryfos Yes I thought about using 6 alphanumeric characters. However using alphanumeric strings as Primary ID slows down the database a lot.

Comment: The idea here is you'd still use the autoincrementing primary id for speed but only use them internally.  Adding them in the `$hidden` array of your models can prevent them from being accidentally exposed in json responses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can suggest three packages for ID generation.

1. **Webpatser's Laravel UUID package**
   Allows the generation of UUIDs for your models, fairly simple to setup and use. This type of ids is unpredictable and might be considered safer, but cannot be sorted in your database.
   [Github](https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid)
2. **Vinkla's Laravel Hashids package**
   Keep your current ids and get a hash that can be decrypted to obfuscate the ids publicly. [Github](https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids)
3. **Hafael's Laraflake package**
   Twitter snowflake like id generation, good performance and better features, ids can be sorted. [Github](https://github.com/hafael/laraflake/)

You can take a look at all three available packages, and choose one, or you can make a DIY solution inspired from those.

Comment: You can use UUID without a package by adding it to your database configuration (see my answer above) A lot quicker and you'll automatic get an UUID on create

Comment: Yes you can, but that package provides a bootstrap with traits that hooks to model to generate ids on different model events, it can be done manually yes, but that package is a convenience to not have to rewrite it all

Comment: Just went with Vinkla's Laravel Hashids package for my current project!

Answer (score 1):

You better use `UUID` instead.

What database type do you use? Most of the database types support the UUID type and can generate them automatic so you don't have to generate them yourself.

Check out:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

Comment: I know about UUI but they aren't URL friendly because they've to many characters.

Comment: @arety_ if that's a problem for you, you can use the PHP function uniqid() to generate a short unique identifier. Ps. it's not a technical problem to use UUID's in your URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UUIDs. I suggest you use the default Laravel string helper method to generate UUIDs. See below on how to achieve this.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$uuid = Str::uuid()->toString(); //this generates a v4 UUID.
```

In your migration, you can specify a `uuid` column like this;

```
**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{ 
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary(); //uuid field set to PK
    });
}
```

In your models, say `User.php`, set the following properties.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id';

public $incrementing = false;

protected $keyType = 'string';
```

I do suggest, you keep an autoincrement column in your tables to help you determine the number of records without writing any queries(This is optional). eg. say such column is `rowId`, you can hide that from your response by adding it to the array of hidden properties on the model. Eg.

```
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token', 'rowId'
];
```

Hope this helps out.

Comment: Yes i know about UUID, however, they've to many characters to use them in userfriendly URLs.